# Running an HDMI projector through SSH

Tags: ssh, hdmi

I have a PI3 with Arch Linux on it, and it is connected to a small projector through hdmi. The PI is headless and I connect to it via ssh.

I would like to launch an X application displaying videos and have it displayed in the projector.

I have tried doing the following, while the raspberry is plugged in and I can see some tty being projected on the wall

```
ssh myraspi
export DISPLAY=:0
startx
```

at which point I get a

```
No screen found (EE)
```

Not sure how to go on from here. A copy of the verbose log is here:

http://pastebin.com/WDpbXAx1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is already started (locally on the pi) you can just start a **x** program true ssh and it wil display om x ( in your case the projector) 
i used this with vlc , just add te parameters to enter in fullscreen

*in my opinion it's nicer to do this with using  a web-biased controller 
https://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_via_a_browser/*

[image: Control_VLC_via_a_browser]

Comment: I will give a shot at starting x manually from the pi. Do you know of any way to  autostarting X without login?

Comment: try "sudo raspi-config" 3 Enable Boot to Desktop/Scratch Choose whether to boot into a desktop environment, Scratch, or the command line

Comment: moe info aboud raspi-config @ https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Comment: if not wok see an other stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830333/start-raspberry-pi-without-login

Comment: @ThreeDiag how dit it go ?

Comment: I don't have access to the Pi now, will give it a try tonight. Thanks for all the info!

Comment: I did it and it was as you suggested. Turns out I was missing a dependency for X to work properly: `xf86-video-fbdev`, once I installed it I tweaked `.xinitrc` to start MPV and show the movies I wanted. Now I have my automated projector/lamp showing cool bits of movies :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't `startx` over `ssh`. You would better go with VNC to run GUI applications on the Pi's screen.

Comment: I don't think that's true, I have seen people online discussing this and allegedly should work, I believe I need to configure the pi properly. I will have a look into vnc

Comment: So let me know when you will find a way how to do that.

Comment: See above answer, it works! Notice that my only purpose was getting something on the screen attached to the PI. I currently have an ssh terminal open on my laptop to control the PI and a movie playing. If you were to start the GUI it would still be unusable (because the mouse and other devices going through X still have to be attached to the PI), but I have read on the internet you could also "hijack" input device to effectively controll the PI remotely via ssh

Comment: But it is something completely different then it was in the question. You are not running `startx` over `ssh`, but showing the windows on the screen locally attached to the Pi.

Comment: I am doing exactly what I reported at the beginning of my question.

From my laptop:
`ssh user@raspi`
`startx -- :0`

then the .xinitrc contains a call to mpv.

Answer (score 0):

If the videos can be played in `omxplayer`, you won't need to start an X session.  Just type `omxplayer -hdmi http://video.example.com/video.mp4` (substituting whatever video URL you want) and it should play.  This does require you to know the video's "final" URL, not just the URL of some page that embeds it, but the huge advantage of `omxplayer` is that it uses the Pi's GPU rather than its CPU, hence it can play high-definition videos even on a Pi Zero (or Zero W) as long as you've set `gpu_mem` high enough in `config.txt` (384 works well, although on a Zero that means you'll have only 128M left and had better not try to run an X desktop without a swapfile).  On the 3, CPU and RAM is not quite so much of a worry as on the Zero, but even so I expect `omxplayer` will work better than VLC et al for a good few videos.

For the final tweak, find out the native resolution of your projector, find out which HDMI mode number is closest to that resolution, and use the `tvservice` command to select it.  E.g. `tvservice --explicit='CEA 3 HDMI'` gives 720x480 (16:9) which works well with the Miroir Mini Projector.  Run this before running `omxplayer` and you should get some nice clear video renditions.